# Discover associated files of a certain process through WMI?

Tags: c#, wmi

Is it possible to determine for a certain process (id), which files are associated to it (i.e. the executable file as well as all files that are currently accessed by the process)?

I have to use WMI unless there is no other option to avoid NtQuerySystemInformation. I already have a piece of code which can determine for a certain file, which processes are currently using it. But I need an efficient way for the opposite direction.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find anything with WMI but if the process is local, you can use the `Modules` of the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class.

```
Process[] processesByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("Myexe.exe");
foreach (ProcessModule module in processesByName[0].Modules)
{
    Console.WriteLine(module.FileName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But your approach is restricted to the binary files (dll or exe) of the process and leaves out data like txt, jpg etc.

Comment: Process Explorer by SysInternals has a way of finding these out so there must be a way (could be unmanaged), but I am afraid I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

As far i know there is not a wmi class to request the open handles for a running process, you must use the [`NtQuerySystemInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724509%28VS.85%29.aspx) function. check this [link](http://www.axcis.com.au/bb/viewtopic.php?p=505) for a demo project using this function in C#.

Comment: Thank you. I have not found any alternative to NtQuerySystemInformation, too. I'll have a look at the demo project.